# Why the observable on frame of UIView only trigger once after subscribing

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactivex

I'm using RxSwift to observe the frame of one UIView. Here is my code in the view

```
self.rx.observe(CGRect.self, #keyPath(UIView.frame))
    .subscribe(onNext: { frame in
        print("Got new frame \(frame)")
    })
    .debug()
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

But it only prints once and won't run the second time when I change view frame. Does anyone know why this happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually you can't, check this [UIView frame/position binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44024755/bind-two-uiview-fram-position-using-rxswift)

Comment: There are undocumented ways of observing this apparently... if you want to live dangerously: [KVO for a UIView frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874288/how-can-i-do-key-value-observing-and-get-a-kvo-callback-on-a-uiviews-frame/19687115#19687115)

Answer (score 0):

This is old post, but I share my code. It works correctly.

```
   self.mapView
            .rx
            .observe(CGRect.self, #keyPath(UIView.frame))
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: CGRect.zero)
            .drive(onNext: { (rect) in
                log.debug("Frame changed to \(String(describing: rect))")
            }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

In here, I tried to observe the ***mapView***'s frame with using ***Driver***.

Hope this help to you.